# запрет просмотра картинки по ПРЯМОЙ(!) ссылке. Варианты

Tags: php, .htaccess, access, img

У пользователя имеются рисунки, альбомы. Просматривать их могут его друзья или только он, или все пользователи.

Кому как выводить хтмл-код

```
<img src = ...
```

решается при помощи бд и php.

НО если ссылку на картинку забукмакают как http://host/fog.jpg , то эту (прямую) ссылку друг (если в настройках указано, что рисунок доступен только для друзей!) может отослать всем (и не зарегистрированным на портале) пользователям всего инета.

Как ограничить такое? Я вообще без понятия :(. И можно ли вообще такое сделать?

Предлагайте варианты. Я обдумаю и буду шото решать.

Comment: Это бессмысленно, так как если будет очень надо, то картинку просто перезальют на какой-нибудь хостинг картинок)

Comment: может действительно не аморачиваться по этому поводу?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Как вариант вы можете все картинки получать через скрипт т.е

```
<IMG SRC='get_image.php?img=111.jpg'>
```

и обработчик get_image.php

```
$file = file_get_contents('secret_path11223344/' . $_GET['img'], true);
echo $file;
```

картинки ложим в папку secret_path11223344

в папке secret_path11223344 создаем файл .htaccess
в нем пишем

```
Order allow,deny
Deny from all
```

Картинку по прямой ссылке увидеть даже зная секретную папку - нельзя.

а скрипт уже сам решит кому что показывать а кому нет....
т.е скрипт читает по известному ему пути картинку и отдает ее.

В данном случае даже если ссылку сохранят как image.php?param=1&param=2 по которой у вас показывается данная картинка вы ее просто можете не показывать по любому вашему критерию - на основе куков, после прошествия какойто даты, для определенного круга IP, только для авторизованных пользователей и т.д

Как дополнение:
если хотите защитить данные то в get_image.php перед чтением добавьте

```
$img = str_replace('/', '', $_GET['img']);
$img = str_replace('\', '', $img);
```

Comment: Я думаю что ваш вариант самый-самый. Простой и понятный. Но я еще подумаю. ааа, ну понятно, что прямой доступ по $_GET['img'] не рекомендуется, но в  вопросе речь не об этом. $_GET['img'] Нужно правильно обработать. И в переменой $_GET['img'] будет передаваться\храниться не имя файла. плюсую ответ!

Comment: да способы проверки входных данных я не описывал, добавил к ответу на вопрос

Comment: эм-м...  что значит параметр true ? Тоесть какой это параметр? http://php.net/manual/ru/function.file-get-contents.php вижу, но не доходит :(. use_include_path ? - но мне можно (нужно) без use_include_path.

Comment: измените на false или уберите его вообще ))

Comment: ЧТО вы мне насоветовали???get_image.php?img=../../../shadow - ?

Но прочесть не удастся. Там же как-бэ есть права доступа. НО что то другое можно прочитать(?)  Поэтому:  НУЖНО вместо имени (fog.jpeg) хранить ид или хэш рисунка в бд, так будет надежнее(?)

Comment: http://itmages.ru/image/view/4303890/9024ba68

Это без обработки ГЕТа. В /etc/passwd паролей нет, но ... :( Незн. может действительно не морочить себе и другим голову. Ведь пользователь может сохранить картинку у себя и разослать всем.

Comment: ааа, ну если с str_replace то думаю сгодится.

Comment: вместо комбинации `file_get_contents` и `echo` будет куда корректней выставить нужные заголовки отдать содержимое с помощью [`readfile()`](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.readfile.php). По ссылке есть как раз нужный пример.

Answer (score 2):

1. Вынести картинки на уровень ниже корневого каталога сайта
   Те, допустим, сайт у вас хранится в директории `/srv/www/site.ru/public` 
   То картинки(и другую приватную информацию) можно хранить, например, в `/srv/www/site.ru/private`
2. Запрет через конфигурацию web-сервера.
   для `apache` можно сделать через `.htaccess`

Comment: первый вариант: Я понял. так и думал сделать И сделал. Но как тогда выводить картинку - она же _выше_ корня. И это не решение проблемы. Хотя readfile читает картинку вне корня. Но это получается просто поток байтов.

Comment: Можно использовать функцию `header`  и сообщить от типе(MIME) выводимых данных.

Comment: ааа, тоесть таким образом поток байтов станет файлом? интересно..тоесть на веб страницу выведеься рисунок:? можно подробнее о header?

Comment: А что такое файл? Это и есть поток байтов. Какого типа файл определяется разными способами. При передаче по HTTP используется указание типа через заголовки ответа. Например, для JPEG `Content-Type: image/jpeg`. Когда web-сервер отдает файл, он смотрит на его тип и выставляет заголовки соответственно этому типу. Если отдавать "в ручную", то и заголовки надо выставлять "руками"

Comment: нужно почитать про header ! Хоть я и использую его в коде но для других цеелей. Всем пасиб. Вохможно еще есть какие-то варианты?

Comment: @root_x Povierennyy  пожалуйста, не пишите комментарии в виде "спасибо". Комментарии служат для разъяснения подробностей вопроса/ответа. Когда у Вас будет достаточно [привилегий](//ru.stackoverflow.com/privileges), Вы сможете голосовать за понравившийся Вам вопрос/ответ, что на сайте Stack Overflow на русском является способом сказать спасибо.

Comment: ясно-понятно, но мне от моего рэйтинга и не жарко, и не тепло.

Comment: а base64 не выход ?

Answer (score 1):

В `.htaccess` (судя по тегу) проверять урл и если урл соотвествует определнному паттерну, прогонять через скрипт, для проверки прав.
например

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/data/(.*)\.(jpg|png|gif)$
RewriteRule ^data/(.*)\.(jpg|png|gif)$ script.php [L]
```

Comment: а без .htaccess ? ааа вижу ewriteRule ^data/(.*)\.(jpg|png|gif)$ script.php [L] - незн будет ли это работать.

Comment: @root_x Povierennyy `nginx` или другой веб сервер? всеравно же через веб сервер картинки пойдут. Принцип остается.

Comment: на локалхосте Апач2 на хостинг-сервера незнаю. А универсальный способ есть? без привязки к веб-серверу. или это и на апаче и на nginx будет работать?

Comment: @root_x Povierennyy если на продакшине шаринг хостинг, то у них как правило стоит `apache`, что бы можно было пользовательский `.htaccess` оставлять для роутинга, кеша и т.д.

Answer (score 1):

Как вариант, можно использовать Base64:

```html
<img alt="Зелёный крест" src="data:image/png;base64,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">
```

Comment: для этого способа ОБЯЗАТЕЛЬНО нужно указывать **правильный** формат (расширение) файла?